# Drawing in window and blank window

Tags: java, window, paint

I have a program that adds points to the list and counts the area of the figure created by these points.
I can not add the screen of that window but I am going to explain what's going on.
I created JFrameForm in Java and I put some labels and text fields on the left, and I left some space on the right to draw the points I added to the list.
The problem is whenever I draw anything the windows is getting blank. Labels disappears and text fields appears when you click them.

My second problem is how to draw sth in other way than paint() function?
Lets say I added the points to the list and when I click a button, I want it to be drawn on the right in my window(using drawOval() or recommend me other function).

//All imports

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawLine(600, 150, 700, 150);
}

public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setLabelFor(jTextField1);
    jLabel1.setText("X: ");
    jLabel1.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));

    jLabel2.setLabelFor(jTextField2);
    jLabel2.setText("Y:");
    jLabel2.setName("labelY"); // NOI18N

    jTextField1.setName("textX"); // NOI18N

    jTextField2.setName("textY"); // NOI18N
    jTextField2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton1.setText("ADD");
    jButton1.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setText("PROCEED");
    jButton2.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 36)); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 126, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(jTextField2))))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 316, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap(419, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(86, 86, 86)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1))
            .addGap(26, 26, 26)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2))
            .addGap(32, 32, 32)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addComponent(jButton2))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 33, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 38, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(24, 24, 24))
    );

    jLabel1.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("labelX");
    jLabel2.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("labelY");
    jTextField1.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("textX");
    jTextField2.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("textY");

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           
protected List<Point> list = new ArrayList<>();
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {        
        list.add(new Point( Integer.valueOf(jTextField1.getText()), Integer.valueOf(jTextField2.getText()) ));
    }catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
    jTextField1.setText("");
    jTextField2.setText("");
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    TwoLists two = new TwoLists(list);

    list = two.sortLists();

    jLabel3.setText("Area: " + Triangularyzacja.countFigureArea(list));
}                                        


public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>


    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });


}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

This is the code (sorry for the style, but do not know how to paste it better).
Its all generated by NetBeans, despite paint() function which is at the beginning and it destroy all the layout(It is getting blank). I have 8 classes more, that contains mechanizm code.

Comment: Please  post some code

Comment: Code has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, you will want a component to draw onto like a JPanel or JLabel or whatever rather than just on the frame itself (and it doesn't matter if the component is transparent (opaque = true). This will give you better control of what goes on further down the road.

Let's say it's a JPanel you placed on your GUI form (say **jPanel1**) and you want to draw on it, you can create and use a method like this one (name the method whatever you like :):

```
public static void drawMyStuff(JPanel panel) {
    // Declare and initialize a graphics object 
    // based on the supplied component.
    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();

    // Set the color we want to use...
    g.setColor(Color.red);

    // Draw a red line horizontally through the 
    // center of the supplied component.
    g.drawLine(0, panel.getHeight()/2, panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight()/2);

    // Close the Graphics object, we don't need it anymore.
    g.dispose();

    // Update the supplied component so as
    // to display what we've drawn.
    panel.revalidate(); 
}
```

Where can you put this method?
In any public class within your project.

How and where would you call this method?

```
drawMyStuff(jPanel1);
```

You can call this method from wherever you like (since it's a public method) as long as reference to the supplied component is obtainable.

Basically then this means that you should call this method from within the same Class that is home to your supplied JPanel unless of course the JPanel itself is public as well.

You may want to call this method perhaps from a JButton **actionPerformed** event:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    drawMyStuff(jPanel1);
}
```

If you prefer to be drawing on a **JLabel** then simply change the parameter declaration within the method declaration,

for example:

```
public static void drawMyStuff(JLabel panel) {....}
```

Or if you do in fact want to draw directly onto the **JFrame** then:

```
public static void drawMyStuff(JFrame panel) {....}
```

If you are going to draw directly onto your **JFrame** form then you would call this method from the extended JFrame Class like:

```
drawMyStuff(this);
```

Now, at the moment the **drawMyStuff()** method is not very functional. It just draws a red line across the center of my supplied component. What if I want to change the color and or line length from time to time dependent upon certain conditions within my application?

In this case then we need to add more parameters to our method declaration and use those parameters to modify our drawn line as needed. Let's add some parameters to our method to also handle color, a line starting point (*in 
pixels*) and a line ending point (*in pixels*). Here's our new method declaration:

```
public static void drawMyStuff(JPanel panel, Color color, int startPoint, int endPoint) { ... }
```

As you can see in our above method declaration we still have our component object which in this case is a **JPanel**, we need this so that our method knows what to draw on. We've also added a Color object parameter conveniently named **color** so that we can supply the color we want our line to be.

We've also added two Integer type parameters named **startPoint** and **endPoint**. The **startPoint** parameter will tell our method where to start our colored line along the X Axis (horizontal plane) within the supplied component. The **endPoint** parameter will tell our method where to end our colored line along the very same horizontal Axis. These two parameters determine the actual length of our line in pixels (endPoint - startPoint = length in pixels).

Now that we have our additional parameters, let's modify the our method code body to accommodate these very same parameters:

```
public static void drawMyStuff(JPanel panel, Color color, int startPoint, int endPoint) {
    // Declare and initialize a graphics object 
    // based on the supplied JPanel.
    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();

    // Set the color we want to use...
    g.setColor(color);  // here we supply our color parameter

    // Draw a red line horizontally through the 
    // center of the supplied JPanel. Notice our 
    // new startPoint and endPoint parameters are
    // supplied here.
    g.drawLine(startPoint, panel.getHeight()/2, endPoint, panel.getHeight()/2);

    // Close the Graphics object, we don't need it anymore.
    g.dispose();

    // Update the supplied JPanel so as
    // to display what we've drawn.
    panel.revalidate(); 
}
```

To call this method we would do it something like this:

```
drawMyStuff(jPanel1, Color.blue, 20, 80);
```

This will draw a blue 60 pixel long line horizontally along the center of jPanel1 starting 20 pixels from the left edge.

I know that drawing a simple line is not what you want to do but you now know how to easily modify this method to make it do whatever you like.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and your engagement! You cleared up some thing to me :)
And simple line is exactly what I want :P I want to draw the points as a coordinates and then link them with lines to create a figure :) It will  just be an additional thing to the program which counts the area of figure by devidin it into triangles :P